# Android ViewPager inside drawelayout takes whole space

Tags: android, drawerlayout

The ViewPager inside DrawerLayout takes up the whole layout screen. Even though the width and height parameters of DrawerLayout are wrap_content,it still takes up the whole space.Has anyone faced similar kind of situation?Enlighten me with the solution..please...

Xml layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<data
    >
   <variable
       name="main"
       type="com.example.jobin.ushop.model.MainActivityModel">
   </variable>
</data>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        >
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
        <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/drawer"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
        >
        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#000000"/>
        <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:id="@+id/navigation"
            app:menu="@menu/drawer_view"
            >
        </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>
        </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</layout>
```

Comment: Most possibly pages of `ViewPager` are taking `match_parent` width/height, which makes `ViewPager` to "wraps its content" to the full width.

Comment: it is not just viewpager, even the button takes up whole space

Comment: I tried including layouts inside include tag in drawerlayout and it works fine.Dont know why